wrong commit info of jgit blame
I have a file , the git blame info of git command git blame a.java like this:

just like the blame info of Jetbrains IDEA "Annotate with Git Blame".

But when I use jgit "BlameCommand" to blame the file, the info is different:

the code comes form jgit github
final BlameResult result = new Git(repo).blame().setFilePath(filePath)
                        .setTextComparator(RawTextComparator.WS_IGNORE_ALL).call();
                final RawText rawText = result.getResultContents();
                for (int i = 0; i < rawText.size(); i++) {
                    final PersonIdent sourceAuthor = result.getSourceAuthor(i);
                    final RevCommit sourceCommit = result.getSourceCommit(i);
                    System.out.println(i + "  " +sourceAuthor.getName() +
                            (sourceCommit != null ? " - " + DATE_FORMAT.format(((long)sourceCommit.getCommitTime())*1000) +
                                    " - " + sourceCommit.getName() : "") +
                            ": " + rawText.getString(i));
                }

look at the commit date , they are different~ so is there a problem with JGIT or am I using the wrong method
to find the problem and solve it

This is likely caused by the timezone. How is DATE_FORMAT defined? What commit time value do you get (the long) with JGit?

Lines 1042 and 1046 have a different change date, in June vs in November. Is that what you're asking about?

Check if you have a .git-blame-ignore-revs file at the root of your repo. If you're using blame on GitHub, GitHub automatically ignores changes from commits listed in this file. The use of this file is to flag commits where, e.g., you're applying a new formatter like prettier or black but not changing code: you don't blame to tell you who ran the formatter, you want blame to tell you who actually modified the code.

But that's just a guess - your output is not completely consistent with what I expect .git-blame-ignore-revs to do, so it may be something else entirely.

In the JGit code, you also have the option RawTextComparator.WS_IGNORE_ALL which I would guess changes the determination of whether a commit touched a line or not, and that could be inconsistent with what git blame does on the CLI. Try the other options documented at https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/RawTextComparator.html, maybe RawTextComparator.DEFAULT which my intuition says is more likely to behave like the CLI.
